# How to register intent in manifest

Tags: android

I am getting the following error in LogCat when running my application. "No Activity found to handle Intent "

The error occurs when pressing button3, the callButton. This tries to bring up a list of contacts to call. It does nothing and after a few more presses the app crashes.

I think I have to add the intent to the manifest but I'm unsure how having, as a newbie, stumbled to this point.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.contactpicker" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactpicker.ContactPicker"
            android:label="All Contacts" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" >
                </action>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
                </category>

                <data
                    android:path="contacts"
                    android:scheme="content" >
                </data>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactpicker.ContactPickerTester"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_picker_tester" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactpicker.ContactDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_detail" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactpicker.ContactDetailFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_detail_fragment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactpicker.ContactsListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactpicker.ContactsListFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts_list_fragment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.contactpicker.ContentProviderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_content_provider" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Other code**

```
    public class ContactPickerTester extends Activity {

    public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_picker_tester);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View _view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri
                        .parse("content://contacts/"));
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        });

        Button insertContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        insertContactButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                insertContactWithIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void insertContactWithIntent() {
        // inserting a new contact using intents//
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity(intent);

        Button callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT): {
                if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    String name = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_contact_textview);
                    tv.setText(name);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Intent` `ACTION_CALL` to make a call

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent );
```

If you need to pick the numbers from contact use `Intent` `ACTION_PICK`

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;

Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); 
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

When you select the contact , you can the get the contact result back in `onActivityResult`

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(column);

        // now you can ACTION_CALL intent to make call
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this works! but i would like to not have any phoneNumber string, (I set it to 0, and when button is clicked it opens up dialler on 0). How can I just open telephone and not use phoneNumber?

Comment: Don't set the data in intent if you need to just open. Also see my updated answer , on how to launch contact and pick the number if required